# Redireccionando en Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Soy nuevo en Ruby on Rails y quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para redireccionar de la acción `New` a la acción `Show`.

Quisiera que se mostrara la página *"show.html.erb"* después de guardar el articulo creado desde la pagina *"new.html.erb"*.

Comment: Un scaffold de rails ya por defecto te hace una redirección, pero en el create, no en new. Creo que en contadas ocasiones deberías hacer una redirección en el new. ¿Por que quieres hacer lo que dices?

Comment: De acuerdo con Alter. En Rails, normalmente la acción `new` se encarga de mostrar la forma para crear un nuevo objeto, mientras que la acción `create` de crear (publicar) el objeto. Si lo ves como un proceso, puede ser: **1)** `new` para mostrar la forma, **2)** `create` para crear (publicar) el objeto, es decir, guardarlo en tu base de datos, y **3)** `show` para mostrar el objeto creado.

Comment: Para comprender un poco mejor las rutas, puedes ir al directorio de tu proyecto desde la terminal e ingresa: `rake routes`. Esto te mostrará todas las rutas que tienes disponibles en este proyecto. Verás cuatro columnas: `Prefix`, `Verb`, `URI Pattern` y `Controller#Action`. En la última columna busca un renglón con `#new` y notarás que en `Verb` tiene `GET` (obtener) mientras que otro con `#create` tendrá `POST` (publicar). La acción `create`, ya que es un `POST` no require de una vista.

Comment: ok @AlterLagos y Horacio gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder y les pido disculpas ya que no formule bien la pregunta. (OJO he usado aqui # y no el arroba para poder publicar el comentario.)  este es parte de mi codigo:                                                                                                                        def show
   #flight = Flight.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    #flight = Flight.new
  end
  def create
    #flight = Flight.new(flight_params)
    if #flight.save
      redirect_to '/flights'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

Comment: lo que quiero saber como puedo hacer para que se redireccione a la pagina show una vez creado el articulo y no a la pagina index.    este codigo (redirect_to '/flights') me redirecciona a la pagina localhost:3000/flights pero quiero que se muestre localhost:3000/flights/1 o 2 o 3 cual sea que sea el id

Comment: @erickson para la próxima edita tu pregunta y agrega ahí tu código, no en los comentarios. Ese es el lugar donde debería ir ese tipo de contenido ya que se puede leer mejor que en un comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para redireccionar al terminar un `create` a `show` tienes que usar:

```
redirect_to action: :show
```

o también serviría en tu caso:

```
redirect_to flight_path(@flight)
```

Comment: probe con redirect_to action: :show y me muestra estoActionController::UrlGenerationError in FlightsController#create

Comment: esto me sirvio: redirect_to flight_path(@flight) muchas gracias @AlterLagos

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se necesita redireccionar al `show` de un objeto, también se puede realizar directamente:

```
redirect_to @flight
```

Y También puedes agregar un mensaje:

```
redirect_to @flight, notice: "El vuelo se guardó correctamente."
```